# Take the sum of 3 adc data for 3 sampling

Tags: verilog

Hi everyone,

I am a newbie in programming FPGA by verilog language. At the present, I am trying to design the firmware to calculate the sum of adc data at 3 sampling. Firstly, I will explain about one adc at one sampling in my code. When you look at the code, you can see that with **rising-edge of clkr clock** and **adcIfEnb == 1**, the **adc_data** will get the value from **adcIfData** and this is the data for **one sampling**. In the next **rising-edge of clkr clock** and **adcIfEnb == 1**, this data is stored in **iradcTrg**. Finally, I will have the 3 data of **adc_data** for 3 sampling which are stored in **iradcTrg** and then I summarize 3 these data.

```
wire adcIfData[79:0];
reg 
always @(posedge clkr) begin
if(adcIfEnb) begin
adc_data[9:0] <= adcIfData[9:0];
end
end
reg [29:0] iradcTrg;
reg [9:0]  adcTrg; 
always @(posedge clkr) begin
if (adcIfEnb) begin 
iradcTrg[29:0] <= {adc_trg[19:10],adc_trg[9:0],adc_data[9:0]};
adcTrg[9:0] <= adc_trg[29:20] + adc_trg[19:10] + adc_trg[9:0];
end
end
```

However, there are 2 problems which I do not know how to solve.

Firstly, at the beginning time, when the first data of **adc_data** is stored at **iradcTrg** and **adcTrg** also take the sum. It means that **adcTrg = 0 + 0 + first_adc_data** but this sum need to be avoided.

Secondly, according to my design, I see that **adc_data** is serialized into **iradcTrg**. It means that the **adc_data** will be stored like this:

[1 2 3] 4 5 6 => 1 [2 3 4] 5 6=> 1 2 [3 4 5] 6

But in my case, I would like that the **adc_data** will be stored like this to get the sum

[1 2 3] 4 5 6 => 1 2 3 [4 5 6]

Therefore, how should I repair my code to get the result that I expected or are there any documents can help me in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start: make sure your code is correctly indented when you put it on stackexchange. 
Secondly: I assume you have edited the code before posting it here because that code will not compile e.g. there is a floating 'reg' at the top and no module declaration.
Thirdly: you have defined a wire adcIfData[79:0] I am going to assume you meant that to be [9:0].
Forthly: You use variables which are not defined: adc_data, adc_trg. 

Fifthly: I suggest you give your variables more meaningfull names like: gater_samples, sum_off_samples.

Now lets look at the core of the code. You want to take samples and shift them into a 30 bit register. There is no need to write "adc_trg[19:10],adc_trg[9:0]" adc_trg[19:0] will suffice. Also there is no need to put it in a different register beforehand. I would just use:

```
always @(posedge clkr) 
   if (adcIfEnb) 
      iradcTrg[29:0] <= {iradcTrg[19:0],adcIfData[9:0]};
```

As to your basic problem of gathering samples and not using the first two: all you have to do is add a counter which counts to three. Then you add the result on the third count. You will need a reset to give the counter a known value at startup but I don't see a reset signal. I always try to use minimal logic so I would make iradcTrg 20 bits wide to only store the intermediate result and at the count of three add it up with the latest sample. Saves another 10 registers. Here is some code. I wrote this without simulating or compiling. It is just a guide of how it all should look like.

```
reg [ 1:0] count;
reg [19:0] gather_samples;
reg [ 9:0] sum_of_samples;
reg        sum_valid;

always @(posedge clkr) 
begin
   if (some_reset)
      count <= 2'd0;
   else
   if (adcIfEnb) 
   begin
      if (count==2'd2)
      begin // third sample arriving, add it to the previous 2
         sum_of_samples <= gather_samples[19:10] + gather_samples[9:0] + adcIfData;   
         count <= 2'd0;
      else
      begin // intermediate: gather samples
         gather_samples <= {gather_samples[9:0],adcIfData};
         count <= count + 2'd1;
      end
      sum_valid <= (count==2'd2);                
   end // if (adcIfEnb) 
end // clocked
```

Answer (score 1):

Your job will be much easier if you use a state machine. Here's a small (and incomplete) example of a state machine.

```
parameter FIRST_DATA=0, SECOND_DATA=1, THIRD_DATA=2, OUTPUT=3;
reg [2:0] current_state = FIRST_DATA;

reg [9:0] adc_data1;
reg [9:0] adc_data2;
reg [9:0] adc_data3;
reg [11:0] adc_data_sum;

always @ (posedge clk)
begin
// TODO: use proper reset
case (current_state):
FIRST_DATA:
    if(adcIfEnb):
        current_state <= SECOND_DATA;
SECOND_DATA:
    if(adcIfEnb):
        current_state <= THIRD_DATA;
THIRD_DATA:
    if(adcIfEnb):
        current_state <= OUTPUT;
OUTPUT:
    if(adcIfEnb):
        current_state <= FIRST_DATA;
endcase
end

always @ (negedge clk)
begin
    if (current_state == FIRST_DATA && adcIfEnb)
        adc_data1 <= adcIfData;
end

always @ (negedge clk)
begin
    if (current_state == SECOND_DATA && adcIfEnb)
        adc_data2 <= adcIfData;
end

always @ (negedge clk)
begin
    if (current_state == THIRD_DATA && adcIfEnb)
        adc_data3 <= adcIfData;
end

always @ (negedge clk)
begin
    if (current_state == OUTPUT)
         adc_data_sum <= adc_data1 + adc_data2 + adc_data3;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Few comments first:

1) I don't know why do you introduce so many variables with strange names. You only need a `adc_buffer` and `adc_sum`. Is `iradcTrg` the same as `adc_trg`? Why is there an empty reg statement? Why adcIfData has 80 bits and you only use 8 LSB bits? I'm confused.

2) Since `adc_sum` will be a sum of 3 (`adcTrg` in your case), think about possible overflow. What should be the width of `adc_sum` if you want to add 3 10-bit numbers?

3) Shouldn't you reset your design to a known state using asynchronous or synchronous reset first?

You can use a 2 bit counter with async reset and a logic for wrapping back to 0:

```
    reg [1:0] adc_buffer_counter_reg;
    always @(posedge clkr or negedge rst_n) begin
      if (!rst_n)
        adc_buffer_counter_reg <= 2'd0;
      else if (adcIfEnb) begin
        if (adc_buffer_counter_reg == 2'd2) //trigger calc of the sum here
          adc_buffer_counter_reg <= 2'd0;
        else
          adc_buffer_counter_reg <= adc_buffer_counter_reg + 2'd1;
    end
```

You can use this counter to trigger a calculation of the sum every 3rd valid data.